# Horizontal scrolling appears unwanted on a one page site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, horizontal-scrolling

I have a website that uses twitter's bootstrap grid and I made it into a one page scroller. I noticed that on the right side of the screen there is about 100px of white space that causes scrolling.

I don't get why this scrolling is here, I tried checking my widths and margins but couldn't find anything, most of the things are just set to '100%', that should fix it right?

I tried looking at other cases of this problem but couldn't find anything they did wrong in my code. I hope someone can find the problem because I just don't have a clue.

Comment: I'm using Internet Explorer 11 here and there are no horizontal scrollbars. Not even if I make the window really tiny. What browser and which version of that browser are you experiencing this problem in?

Comment: I have this in safari 7.0.1 and the newest versions of firefox and chrome. I'm using a mac if that matters.

Comment: Horizontal scrollbar are on the ultra bottom of the page... What does the moveWindow() function do ?

Comment: it's the inline style overflow:auto in your html and body tag that causing this problem. set overflow to hidden

Comment: @Jahnux73 it makes that the page moves the window to the second section on load.

Answer (score 1):

**1st issue**

is that there is a to wide div in your content this one :`<div class="col-lg-12 referenties">` it has `width:100%;` and `margin-left:5%`. So you either have to remove that margin either set `width:95%;`

This solves part of the problem.

**2nd issue**

The parent of `<div class="col-lg-12 referenties">` which is a `<div class="row">` has `margin-left: -15px;` and `margin-right: -15px;` so this div is to wide for the window. The easiest way is to delete those margins.

Nothing to do with `display:table;` my bad.

Comment: Well a quick fix is certainly better than nothing, thank you!

Comment: @Kelly Updated my answer, found the bug